# How to make my calculation more accurate

Tags: c#, datetime

I work on a calculator when I try to receive precisely the amount of vacation used for one single month.

This works perfectly when I book a hole day . But if I want to a some hours or just a 1/2 it is "not working" it is displayed as a whole day.

How can I make my calculation more precise ?

```
    public double[] GetMonthReport(int year)
    {
        double[] yearMonths = new double[13];
        if (this.HtVacationDays.Any())
        {
        }
        {
            foreach (ZvVacationDay vacationDay in this.ZvVacationDay)
            {
                foreach (DateTime vacationDayDate in vacationDay.GetDates())
                {
                    if (vacationDayDate.Year == year)
                    {
                        yearMonths[vacationDayDate.Month] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return yearMonths;
    }
```

In my ZvVacationDay I have FromDate (datetime) and a ToDate(datetime) and also a title as varchar  etc...

Here is a example for my data in the db. now for a "whole" day of vacation

**FromDate 2009-08-17 08:00:00:000 ToDate 2009-08-17 16:00:00:000**

Thanks for help and fast answer !

Comment: So you're getting the _date_.  How do you get the _number of hours_?

Comment: Also your `if` statement is not executing anything - it has an empty (`{` `}`) block after it.

Comment: How will you be able to tell that someone only had half a day off?

Comment: Please, show what data RAVacationDays have

Comment: @DStanley I could receive  the from date and to date from the "vacationDay" well maybe I can get the hours from there ?

Comment: This isn't even valid C# code; the outer `foreach` loop is broken (*"type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement"*).

Comment: @dvnrrs I don't think so because my Visual Studio has no problem with that code

Comment: @dvnrrs See my edit. It's a fairly obvious typo in the copy paste

Comment: @TamoDaleko and what is returned by `GetDates()`?

Comment: Please add some example values of `FromDate` and `ToDate` for a full- and half-day vacation.

Comment: @DStanley I have edited my question should be now more clear what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo-code would be:

```
        if (vacationDayDate.Year == year)
        {
            if({isHalfDay})
                yearMonths[vacationDayDate.Month] += 0.5;
            else   // is full day
                yearMonths[vacationDayDate.Month]++;
        }
```

Or more succinctly:

```
        if (vacationDayDate.Year == year)
        {
            yearMonths[vacationDayDate.Month] += {isHalfDay} ? 0.5 : 1.0;
        }
```

Comment: my I ask what is  if({isHalfDay}) ?

Comment: IT's whatever you have to determine if the vacation is a half or whole day.

Comment: well this was the point of my question more or less how can make my  calculation more accurate ...

Comment: Do `FromDate` and `ToDate` have a time component or is it always just the date?

Comment: they are datetime in the db so yes

Comment: But does the _data_ include time?  Add some sample data to your question for both cases.

Comment: i got it by myself but thx for your tip done it more or less the same

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know how much time they took off.

You could either store Days off as a number of hours/part days off so your iteration becomes

```
foreach(TimeSpan vacationTimeOff in vacationDay.GetTimeOff())
```

or have a `RAHalfVacationDays` and iterate over that.

As soon as you have the partial days as a datasource it becomes trivial

```
yearMonths[vacationDayDate.Month] += timeOff;
```